# Number of Jordan boxes of size j for eigenvalue $\lambda$ is $2\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^j-\dim\ker(A-\lambda I)^{j+1}-\dim \ker(A-\lambda I)^{j-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

My question is about the computation of the Jordan normal form. Let $K$ be field. Let $A \in K^{n \times n}$ be a matrix, that characteristic polynomial splits into linear factors over $K$. I've learned that the number of Jordan boxes of size $j$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is given by $$c_j(\lambda, A):=2\dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^j - \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^{j+1} - \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^{j-1}.$$ I want to prove this fact.  Let $J$ be the Jordan normal of $A$. I have already shown that

$$c_j(\lambda, J)=c_j (\lambda, A).$$
What is left to show is that the number of Jordan boxes of size $j$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $J$ can be computed by
$$2\dim \ker (J - \lambda I)^j - \dim \ker (J - \lambda I)^{j+1} - \dim \ker (J - \lambda I)^{j-1}.$$
Thanks.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2441810/jordan-form-number-of-blocks?rq=1) answer your question? (Note it gives the number of blocks of size at least $j$, and then subtracting those two numbers gives the formula you want.)

Comment: (I am also worried that your formula should be $c_{j+1} - 2c_j + c_{j-1}$ instead. Note that the formula in your title and in your post are different.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff you are right. It should be $2 c_J$. I will edit it thank you. I  believe the $+$ and $-$ are right because I'm talking about dimension, not rank? I actually saw the question you shared but I don't get it.

Comment: I have added an answer in that post, since I noticed the second question was not answered, and that's the one you want. Does it help? (And yes, sorry, your signs are correct.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Yes, it helped. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Would it be OK if I closed this as a duplicate of that one, now that it has full answers?

Comment: yes @PedroTamaroff