# Minimal Polynomial Exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

$\newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}$Let $E$ be a vector space. We are given a matrix $A$ that has a characteristic polynomial $q(t) = -(t-2)^5$. We know that $\dim\Ker(A-2I)^2 = 3$ and $\dim\Ker(A-2I)^4 = 5$. We are asked to find the minimal polynomial of $A$.

This is what I've done so far: since $\dim\Ker(A-2I)^4 = 5 = \dim(E)$, $m_A(x)$ has to divide $(x-2)^4$. Besides, $\dim*\Ker(A-2I)^2 = 3$ implies that $m_A(x)$ does not divide $(x-2)^2$. Therefore, we are left with two candidates for the minimal polynomial of $A$: $(x-2)^4$ or $(x-2)^3$. I don't know how to decide between these two.

Comment: from my understanding, one way to find minimal polynomial, first find Jordan Canonical form, then remove all Jordan blocks except the largest Jordan block for each eigenvalue, and lastly calculate characteristic polynomial of that matrix.

Comment: Also the dimension of null space of $(A-2I)^k$ will always increase until certain point, after it reaches that point it will never change. So you can find that dimension of null space of $A-2I$ is 2 (thus we will get two Jordan blocks) and dimension of null space of $(A-2I)^3=4$. So you have two Jordan blocks, one is $1\times1$, second one is $4\times4$, and as I mension before, minimal polynomial is equal to characteristic polynomial of largest $4\times4$ matrix

Comment: How do you find these dimensions?

Comment: If $\mathrm{dimKer}(A-2I)=1$, it means you have just one jordan block, and $\mathrm{dimKer}[(A-2I)^i]=i$. Because we are given that $\mathrm{dimKer}[(A-2I)^2]=3$, we conclude that $\mathrm{dimKer}(A-2I)=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Since the characteristic polynomial splits, the matrix has a Jordan canonical form.

Because the minimal polynomial divides $(x-2)^4$, the largest block is at most $4\times 4$; so there are at least two blocks.

If the largest block is $3\times 3$, then you either have three blocks (a $3\times 3$ and two $1\times 1$), or two blocks (a $3\times 3$ and a $2\times 2$). In the first case, the dimension of the nullspace of $A-2I$ is $3$ (the number of blocks), and the dimension of the nullspace of $(A-2I)^2$ is $4$; so that’s not the situation you have.

In the latter case, the dimension of the nullspace of $A-2I$ is $2$, but the dimension of $(A-2I)^2$ is $4$; again, not the case you have.

That means the largest block is $4\times 4$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that $$ \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^k - \dim \ker (A - \lambda I)^{k-1}$$ gives you the number of blocks corresponding to $\lambda$ of size at least $k$. See, for example: [Jordan form, number of blocks.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2441810)

So in this case you know that $\dim\ker(A-2I)^2 = 3$ and $\dim\ker(A-2I)^4 = 5$. Let us consider the three possibilities for $\dim\ker(A-2I)^3$.

- $\dim\ker(A-2I)^3=3$ is not possible. This would imply that $\dim\ker(A-2I)^k=3$ for each $k\ge 2$. (Also, this would mean that there are no blocks of size $\ge3$, which would lead to $(A-2I)^2=0$. Which is another way to get a contradiction.)
- $\dim\ker(A-2I)^3=5$ would mean that there are $5-3=2$ blocks of size at least $3\times3$. This is not possible in a $5\times 5$ matrix.
- So only one possible case remains: $\dim\ker(A-2I)^3=4$. We get $4-3=1$ block of size at least $3\times3$, and also $5-4=1$ block of size at least $4\times 4$. The Jordan form has one block $4\times4$ and one block $1\times1$.
  $$J=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
  \end{pmatrix}$$ This gives us $m_A(x)=m_J(x)=(x-2)^4$.